# Outlook webmail access mailto body is blank

Tags: html, email, url, mailto, outlook-web-app

I am trying to create a `mailto` url for Outlook (web version).

On Outlook everything works perfectly fine, but now I have to implement it on web version OWA as well, so I am struggling with this url:

```
<a href='https://company.domain.com/owa/?ae=Item&a=New&t=IPM.Note&to=someone@expample.com&subject=Hello%20again&body=Body%20Text' target=_blank>testy</a>
```

Because the body part is empty. Any ideas on what's happening?

Answer (score -1):

Please try change the @ in email to %40:

```
&to=someone@expample.com -> &to=someone%40expample.com
```

It worked for me:
https://outlook.live.com/owa/?path=/mail/action/compose&to=service%40domain.com&subject=Customer+Service+Request&body=Add+Your+Request+here

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Please don't use any other image upload/screengrab service other than what is supplied in your editor by Stack Overflow. Most users will not open your screenshot if it's not hosted by the _i.stack.imgur_. I have edited your answer and uploaded your screenshot the correct way.

Comment: It doesn't work. As I said, I am using Microsoft Outlook Web App, not outlook.com or office365. It is different, because it is hosting as exchange server.

Comment: @BinaryTie This is not the reason to down vote the answer. It is always easy to say "it doesn't work", but it's hard to come up with some answer. At least appreciate the suggested solution and time someone spent to look into your issues. I also would advise you to modify your question and include exactly platform and the version you are using.

Comment: @SlavaIvanov I did not down voted. Also I wrote that provided answer is not working in a comment. I appreciate for time and suggestions , I am also trying lot of different things and as soon I found it I will share came up solutions fast as I can.